# Uncaught Error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found

Tags: php, dll, httprequest

Below is my PHP code:

```
$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://api.cc.email/v3/contacts/contact_id');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_GET);

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'Cache-Control' => 'no-cache',
  'Authorization' => 'Bearer {access_token}',
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
  'Accept' => 'application/json'
));

try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

It gives the error:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found

I got the solution from so. And I tried:

1. Downloaded **php_http.dll** from http://originaldll.com/file/php_http.dll/19366.html
2. put the dll in *D:\Xampp\php\ext*
3. add `extension = php_http.dll` in *php.ini*
4. restart the system.

But the error is still there. How can I fix this?
My php version is: **7.1.8**

Comment: Show how you include script with class HttpRequest. Or maybe do you use PSR-4 autoloading. Try
new \HttpRequest()

Comment: Also find in output of phpinfo() string 'HttpRequest'

Comment: @RomanAngelovskij, there is no `HttpRequest` in `phpinfo()`

Comment: Hey! I'm stuck with the same problem. My PHP version is also 7.1, can you share your solution @DeepuSasidharan

Comment: @Sameer, Since the HttpRequest() is not working, I am using php curl for v3 api